# Trying To Delete MongoDB Document In Ajax Keep Getting Error 404 'CANNOT DELETE'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I want to be able to delete a specific item in my MongoDB when I click on a button using the "gameName" value. When I do this I keep getting error 404 'Cannot Delete'. What I am doing wrong here? Thank you.

Here is the request:

```
function deleteGame() {
$('#js-games').on('click', '.delete', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('delete button works')
    var id = $(this).parent().data('id');
    console.log(id);
$.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: '/favorites' + '/' + id,
    success: getYourGames(),
})
    var gone = 'Your time was deleted!';
    $('.js-type-game').html(gone);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.js-type-game').fadeOut(gone).html('').fadeIn();
        }, 2000);
})
```

}

And here is the router.delete:

```
router.delete('/gameName', (req, res) => {
favorite.delete(req.params.gameName);
console.log(`Deleting game \`${req.params.gameName}\``);
res.status(204).end();
});
```

Comment: Where are you deleting the MongoDB document?

Comment: So basically I 'get' back a list of game names that renders on the DOM. Each item on the DOM has a 'delete' button. So when I click on that button I want to be able to delete that item from the list. Does this help?

Comment: I meant where are you deleting the document on the server side, not the front end

Comment: I actually just got it to work! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've accidentally defined an explicit `/gameName` route. To define a parameter you need to use a colon, i.e.:

```
router.delete('/:gameName', (req, res) => { // with colon (:)
    favorite.delete(req.params.gameName); // req.params.gameName is now correct
    console.log(`Deleting game \`${req.params.gameName}\``);
    res.status(204).end();
});
```